# iOS9 Safari Web App with Camera Invocation - Orientation Issue

Tags: safari, camera, orientation, ios9, portrait

I've been working on a web app - primarily built for iOS Safari and Android Chrome - that allows users to take a picture and then import it into the application. The app requires the user to have landscape orientation before accessing the camera feature, because our application requires the photo to be a certain aspect ratio in the ballpark of 16:9. The app also requires landscape mode after importing the picture because the app is optimized for landscape. We have a modal to say, 'Please flip your phone to landscape for best experience.'

The issue is specifically with Safari iOS9. Once you take the picture and return to the web app, the phone thinks you are in portrait mode even though you're holding it horizontally. This happens even if you cancel the import and go back.

Basically, the phone automatically goes to portrait mode and ignores your actual orientation after using the native image upload/capture component.

So to get back into the application currently, the user is required to rotate their phone twice (once to get fully into portrait mode, and again to go back to landscape mode).

Facebook has the same problem. Twitter has seemed to figure it out quite nicely, though.